# Save the AWS Cognito JWT Keys Locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-cognito

Instead of obtaining the AWS Cognito JWT Keys from:

```
https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{user_pool_id}/.well-known/jwks.json
```

I'm considering speeding up the script by pre-fetching this jwks.json file and saving it locally. I'm unsure how frequently the keys change, but I can eventually leave a daily crontab to ensure the file is updated daily.

**I'm wondering if there's any drawback with this approach that I am missing?**

Comment: Cache them https://support.okta.com/help/s/article/What-is-the-recommended-approach-to-take-when-caching-the-Okta-JSON-Web-Keys-SetJWKS-for-OAuth?language=en_US